# "xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default" for Guest CENTOS 6.6, HOST OS Windows 7 enterprise

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox, xrandr, resolution

I am getting the following errors:

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
>   minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768 default
>   connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm    1024x768       61.0*     800x600
>   61.0      640x480        60.0

When I am trying to increase my Guest OS resolution to `1290X1080`, while tried following steps mentioned [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem). Prior to that I was able to change the resolution by the above mentioned steps, but after a update to `CENTOS 6.5 to 6.6`, I am facing this error.Lots of people are having the same problem, but no solution I could not get my issue resolved.

My current system configuaration:

```
GUEST OS        : CENTOIS 6.6
HOST OS         : WIndows 7 enterprise
Display Adapter : Intel HD 
VirtualBox      : 4.6.3
VBoxGuestaddition is also succesfully installed and up and running
```

The result from CENTOS, when I do a **`lspci -vnn`**

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ lspci -vnn 
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] [8086:1237] (rev 02)
    Flags: fast devsel

00:01.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II] [8086:7000]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:01.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE [8086:7111] (rev 01) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64
    [virtual] Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable)
    [virtual] Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable)
    I/O ports at d000 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: ata_generic, pata_acpi, ata_piix

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter [80ee:beef] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Kernel modules: vboxvideo

00:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:001e]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d010 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000
    Kernel modules: e1000

00:04.0 System peripheral [0880]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service [80ee:cafe]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at d020 [size=32]
    Memory at f0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at f0800000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Kernel driver in use: vboxguest
    Kernel modules: vboxguest

00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller [8086:2415] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0000]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at d100 [size=256]
    I/O ports at d200 [size=64]
    Kernel driver in use: Intel ICH
    Kernel modules: snd-intel8x0

00:06.0 USB controller [0c03]: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB [106b:003f] (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 22
    Memory at f0804000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:07.0 Bridge [0680]: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI [8086:7113] (rev 08)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 9
    Kernel modules: i2c-piix4

00:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:001e]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0820000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d240 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use
```

Any solution to this problem ?

**EDIT 2 :**

I am able to get it solve to some extent by editing(creating) `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11/` , the file code I am sharing below

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
        HorizSync   28.0 - 70.0
        VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "VMware SVGA"
        Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
                Modes     "1920x1080_60.00"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Now what is the problem ?**

Actually  after creating the xorg.conf file I am able to get few more resolution, but not the one(**1920*1080**) resolution .

[image]

Comment: I flagged your other question as a duplicate of this one, so we only have one place to work from.  Try reading [this support post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=65283), and deleting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`  After doing so, tell me if XOrg autoconfigures correctly.  If that doesn't help, either upgrade CentOS to 7 or downgrade VirtualBox as the post suggests.

Comment: Nope @eyoung100 dude, the one I asked here, I was able to solve this by editing(creating) xorg.conf file. Now I am able to get few more resolution but not the desired resolution of 1920*1080

Comment: Include the information from your other question here, by editing the above post, so that readers know the problems are related, and then read the link I gave you.  Even with a `xorg.conf` file, I would hazard a guess that you can't get above 1024x768, as the post suggests.

Comment: Oh my gosh ... is it ?

Comment: @eyoung100 I am able to get resolution higher than 1024x768 etc but not only 1920*1080 , see the screenshot

Comment: Your `mode` line is incorrect.  Remove `_60`.  If that doesn't work install CentOS 7 in a new VM.  If the problem disappears upgrade 6.6 to 7.0 in your old VM, using the [unsupported upgrade method](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool), and then read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177414/upgrading-centos-6-6-to-7).  Note I said, <b>unsupported</b>