# 1920 1080 resolution is not showing up [VBOX Cent OS 6.6]

Tags: centos, xorg, display, resolution

MY `/etc/X011/xorg.conf` has the following configuration, but its not showing up 1920x1080 resolution in Guest `centos 6.6`

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
        HorizSync   28.0 - 70.0
        VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
                Modes     "1152x768" "1920x1080"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Anyone facing this kind of issue ? Please help

Comment: Have you installed the Guest Additions in the Guest.... it takes some work in RPM based distros... If you need help, I'll write up an answer...

Comment: Yup I have installed Guest addition .. nd m able to share files between guest nd host os .. definately I need answer , please write it up ! Thanks

Comment: Were there any errors during the install of the Guest Additions? Please upload a photo of the terminal, after the reinstall, but before you press enter.  I have 2 hunches I need verified.

Comment: Nope no errors I encountered , it installed successfully

Comment: Please refer this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209157/xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-default-for-guest-centos-6-6-h